# Best tools to produce screencasts in Linux?

Tags: linux, screencasts

I would like to make some screencasts to teach programming in Linux. Ideally they should be able to:

- Record, of course, what is happening in the screen (ideally they should be able to record only specific zones).
- Zoom / highlight.
- Annotate.
- Record audio (an explanation about what's happening).
- Support subtitles.

It would be highly desirable that they have good compression rates and several output formats (Eg. video, flash).

Comment: Consider making this community wiki.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### 1. RecordMyDesktop

You can use [RecordMyDesktop](http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/about.php) which can be setup to capture sound too.

#### 2. Istanbul

[Istanbul](http://live.gnome.org/Istanbul) is a gnome app to record your desktop

#### 3. Screentoaster

You can also use [screentoaster](http://www.screentoaster.com/) which is an online service that is platform independent and relies on java. (It works a treat.)

#### 4. VLC

You can pre-record the sound and then use [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/) by going

1. Media
2. Convert/Save
3. Capture Device
4. Capture Mode to "Desktop"
5. Set frame rate
6. Capture/Save
7. Set File Name

you can then use [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) or Mencoder (which is part of [Mplayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/news.html)) to merge the audio and video file.

#### 5. ffmpeg

In fact [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) can also be use on its own to save a screencast by doing

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -s 1280x800 -r 60 -i :0.0 ~/name.mpg
```

replace 1280x800 by your resolution and 60 by your desired fps.

you can record the sound using [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/), and then merge the audio and video files. (shouldn't be too hard to set up a script that starts both apps at once, etc...)

#### Subtitles, Zooming, editing, etc

Subtitles Can be added using [KSubtitle](http://ksubtile.sourceforge.net/). You can also use [The Open Movie Editor](http://www.openmovieeditor.org/) to do this, (but you'll need to use png images, which isn't ideal) and [Pitivi](http://www.pitivi.org) or [cinefx](http://www.cinefx.org/) for editing your video. Avidemux will also add subtitles to an avi file as shown [here](http://apapad.blogspot.com/2007/06/ubuntu-hot-to-add-subtitles-to-avi-file.html)

It'll be really hard to find all the features you request in a single tool. I advice first getting a nice video/audio file and then editing it with zooms, annotations, etc... It really doesn't matter what format you capture, since you'll be able to convert using ffmpeg.